# How to load load jquery before the page loads

Tags: jquery, html, css, helper

I want to add some jquery to a page before it loads the actual website.

I found some code but it doesn't seem to work?
Sort of like a loading bar or gif image to display first, before the actual page.
I cannot give you the website as I'm working on localhost.

I have used this for help with my code - maybe I have placed it in the wrong place? [Click here for link](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/)

The first and last bit of code I added to my header.php and the second I added to CSS stylesheet...?

Please help!
Thaaaank you!

Comment: Put your jquery script in `<head>`

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
 $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>

Comment: Tushar, I have placed the code above in my header.php file inside my <head> tags

Answer (score 0):

So when it comes to a loading image like that there are quite a few ways to do it. You could just have an image positioned in the front so that it covers the entire page. Then do something like:

```
$(document).load(function() {
  $('your-img-here').fadeOut(500);
});
```

However, if the user has JS disabled for whatever reason, they will be staring at a loading GIF for all eternity.

Another option, though it has render blocking JS, is to position the image accordingly, something like:

```
#your-img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

This will have the image there, but it is not displayed. Then, in the , call a bit of JS that displays the image. That way, if JS is disabled, the loading GIF just won't fire.

In case you are wondering, the document.load does not fire until the document is completely loaded.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hey Kyle,

Thank you. I understand but I'm very new to jquery and not sure what to call exactly...

Comment: We've all been there my friend. So the document.load is going to be what makes it disappear. Also, make sure you have a jquery library linked in order for that to work. In order to make it appear, using jquery, you just do something like $('your-img').show(); Jquery selectors are exactly like your css selectors.